# Como colocar uma imagem dentro da popover do bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Eu quero colocar uma imagem dentro da popover. Alguém sabe se isso é possível?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tipo isso: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Ek2nl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá só precisa de passar um objecto no método .popover()

Retirei o title e o data-content da tag

Veja o seguinte exemplo.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover">Toggle popover</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    title:'Exemplo de imagem em popup', 
    html:true,
    content:'<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></img>'});   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigada! Era exatamente isso que eu queria :)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o evento nativo da função e alterar o conteúdo do popover. Mas há algumas maneiras diferentes de fazer isso, dependendo da sua intenção.

Primeiramente, por se tratar de uma imagem que usa a tag `<img>`, é necessário adicionar o atributo `data-html="true"` no link, para que o conteúdo do popover seja interpretado como HTML e não texto puro:

```
<a href="#" data-html="true"...>
```

Adicione também outro atributo `data-img` com o caminho a imagem:

```
<a href="#" data-html="true" data-img="url_da_imagem"...>
```

Quando o evento `show.bs.popover` (evento que é disparado ao exibir o popover no clique do link) for chamado, você altera o atributo `data-content` (que é o conteúdo do popover) de forma dinâmica, adicionando a tag `<img>` e puxando o caminho da imagem em `data-img`.

No exemplo abaixo o popover já possui o texto. Vou apenas inserir uma imagem após o texto concatenando o texto existente com a tag `<img>`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();  
});

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('show.bs.popover', function(){

   // conteúdo original do popover
   var conteudo = $(this).data("content");
   
   // imagem a ser inserida
   var imagem = '<div><img width="50" src="'+ $(this).data('img') +'"><div>';

   // adiciona uma imagem concatenando com o que já tinha
   $(this).attr("data-content", conteudo+imagem);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-html="true" data-img="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
</div>
```

Você também pode inserir tudo direto no atributo `data-content`, mas para uma melhor visualização do código, é bem melhor usar o evento `show.bs.popover`, pois você pode, inclusive, montar um template e inserir no popover:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();  
});

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('show.bs.popover', function(e){

   // novo conteúdo para o popover
   var conteudo = 'Some content inside the popover<br>'
   +'<img width="50" src="'+ $(this).data('img') +'">';

   // adiciona o conteúdo da variável "conteudo"
   $(this).attr("data-content", conteudo);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-html="true" data-img="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header">Toggle popover</a>
</div>
```

Neste caso acima, você pode até omitir o atributo `data-content` do link `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Não é uma solução muito elegante, mas as vezes pode te ajudar. Vc pode colocar um `background-imagem` no popover, e usar um `linear-gradiente` para cobrir só o fundo do texto para a imagem ão ficar aparecendo no fundo de onde deve estar o texto.

Para vc poder colocar uma imagem em cada popover eu usei o atributo `[data-content^="item1"]` e ele só aplica o estilo no popover que começa o texto com Item1, ali vc coloca sempre a primeira palavra da frase, desde que ela não se repita no início da frase de outro popover.

Fiz duas variações que podem te atender usando `backgroudn-position` e `back-ground-size`. Veja o código para entender melhor como ficou.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  [data-content^="item1"] + .popover {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 60%, #fff 60%, #fff 100%), url(https://placecage.com/100/100) !important;
      background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center ;
    padding: 0 !important;
  } 
  [data-content^="item2"] + .popover {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 60%, #fff 60%, #fff 100%), url(https://placecage.com/100/100) !important;
      background-size: 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    padding: 0 !important;
  } 
  [data-content^="item1"] + .popover .popover-content, [data-content^="item2"] + .popover .popover-content {
      padding-top: 50px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Customizado 1</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="item1 - Some content inside the popover lorem ipsum dolor 123">Toggle popover</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Customizado 2</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="item2 - Some content inside the popover lorem ipsum dolor 123">Toggle popover</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Original</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover lorem ipsum dolor 123">Toggle popover</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**OBS:** Pode ser que vc precise mexer nos valores do linear-gradiente dependendo do tamanho do texto do popover, mas como cada popover tem que ter seu css devido a imagem diferente para cada um vc pode ajustar isso para cada caso.

Como falei essa é apenas uma opção caso não haja algo mais apropriado...